# Is there scan-me-for-vulnerabilities services?

Tags: network-scanners, nmap, vulnerability

Where can I get more similar to [nmap.online-domain-tools.com](http://nmap.online-domain-tools.com/) scan services.

**Edit:** Probably, nobody know what does nmap.online-domain-tools.com is. I'm trying to explain:

- Network service. For example, web-interface without "Registration Form" or "With".
- Kind of security test, implemented on the side of service against guest, if guest will agreed.
- For example, there is test for browser:

  - www.surfpatrol.ru - Inspect holes in your browser
  - acid3.acidtests.org - Developers test for browser, test of working, javascript.
  - ipduh.com/anonymity-check/ - Test for anonymity of your browser.

  The nmap.online-domain-tools.com tests your host machine for all of open ports, services fingerprints on this ports, anomalies, fingerprint of your OS, etc... This is nmap.

I'm looking for similar services to test host, not a browser, not a soft for penetrating / scanning / etc.

My host has Public IP v4, available from the whole the World. In another words: "I'm trying to look at the mirror".

Comment: Is your host publicly available (a web server), or a machine in your home? what do you want to test for?

Comment: See my adding. Yes, i'm interesting in Public IP test.

Comment: @AviD, I've improved my question. Check it again. Yes, it is seeking for Truth. For right ways to test host.

Comment: @litigious.formalism umm... no you haven't? The problem with the question is that questions asking for recommendations of a product / tool / service / *[any other X]* are not a good fit for StackExchange, for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: @AviD, how can I improve my question? For example, I'm trying to imagine such service, similar to nmap.online-domain-tools.com, to test my host, my firewall, my network stack of kernel for modern exploits. This is interesting, what do you think?

Comment: Interesting, yes (at least to some people), but off-topic for this site - because as the links above state, recommendation questions are not a good fit for StackExchange. Please take a few minutes to take the [tour], and check out the [help/on-topic] on this subject.

Comment: We know what nmap is. What kind of testing do you want to do that nmap can't?

Comment: @schroeder, I'm interesting in vulnerabilities. Is my firewall right configured, are my services up-to-date and has no any known holes, for remote-exploitation, etc... Nmap doesn't bring such information, however, metasploit can.

Comment: Testing if your firewall is correctly configured requires custom tests that are designed in respect to your rules. As for services and vulnerability scans, then use metasploit? You are asking for services when you already know what you need to run. Search for vulnerability scanners, if you want other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

NMAP is a tool meant for locating open ports and identify running services on a system. But thanks to the NSE you're capable of running a predefined list of scripts which scan for potential vulnerabilities and even perform exploitation. But you shouldn't rely on NMAP for that.

For vulnerability assessment purposes, there are specialized tools available like Nessus, OpenVAS, etc...